# Wamp Server localhost to dropbox

Tags: localhost, wamp, dropbox, wampserver

I want to move my environment to dropbox so I can work at home and on my laptop elsewhere. I followed [this tutorial](http://abhisheksachan.blogspot.com/2012/08/web-development-environment-made-easy.html).

My big question is: I was able to see all my folders in the root folder (www) when I typed in localhost in the URL; is this not the case anymore or did I mess something up? Won't I be working out of the dropbox root folder rather than the local root folder (G:\wamp\www) now?

Answer (score 0):

Yes! you will not be working in your old wamp root i.e G:\wamp\www as new root folder is your dropbox root. but that won't be problem as you have moved all your files to the new root.